# angular-file-upload to nodejs backend unable to read file contents

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ng-file-upload

I'm using angular file upload which previously did work when I used Laravel Lumen for the backend but I've moved to Node and unable to return the file contents of an upload.

**FRONT END ANGULAR**

```
$scope.upload = Upload.upload({
    url: ENV.apiEndpoint + '/upload',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        fname: $scope.fname
    },
    file: file
}).progress(function(evt) {

}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
});
```

**BACK END NODE**

**upload/index.js**

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./upload.controller');

var router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './my-uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });


router.post('/', upload.single('file'), controller.index);

module.exports = router;
```

**upload/upload.controller.js**

```
'use strict';

var _ = require('lodash');
var db = require('../../db');
var https = require('https');
var Q = require('q');
var fs = require('fs');
var multer = require('multer');

exports.index = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.files.file);
    res.status(204).end();
};
```

**Old Laravel Lumen Request**

```
public function data(Request $request) {

    $path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = $path_parts['extension'];
    $contents = file_get_contents( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] );
    return response()->json(['type'=> $extension, 'content'=> $contents]);
}
```

All I'm looking to do is upload a file but only return the contents of the file to the front end again I dont want the file to be stored.

Comment: req.file instead of req.files

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example, you have a couple of things wrong. Check it out

```
 var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'public/images/banks')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(16, function (err, raw) {
      cb(null, raw.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname));
    });
  }
});
var upload = multer({storage: storage});

router.post('/uploadImage', upload.single('file'), function (req, res, next) {
  if(!req.file) {
    res.status(400);
    res.send({error: 'No se pudo subir el archivo'});
  }

  res.send({filename: req.file.filename});
});
```

Comment: This actually gives me `Undefined` when returning `req.file` and states `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined`

Comment: Then you are not uploading the file properly from the front.

Comment: In your front function you have a variable not defined: file: file. That file is not defined anywhere, at least it's not seen in the code you put.